# How to switch environments for open jupyter notebook

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

If open a python jyputer notebook in vscode, then try to execute the notebook (so a kernel starts) and realize I need to activate a different environment, there doesn't seem to be a way to switch environments without completely quitting VSCode and coming back in.

If can switch environments in the terminal window or using the environment picker in the lower left, but it there doesn't seem to be a way to quit the current kernel and have it re-launch under the new environment.  I've tried using the "Restart Kernel", closing the notebook and re-opening.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm a developer on this extension. The intention was for this feature to function as the Python Interactive Window did, where you could use the VSCode Interpreter picker to change out an open notebook to a new kernel. However it appears that we have a hitch that we shipped with this functionality. There is already an issue open in our github here which I believe that you filed (just going on user name match :)):

https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/7862

That will be the right place to track our progress on fixing this, and it's on our immediate backlog.

Comment: Yup.  That's me.  Thanks.